# Using GetLastAutoGenValue

Tags: delphi, informix, delphi-xe5, firedac

I am using fireDAC TFDQuery to insert values in informix database, using below code snippet:

```
with QHeaderQuery do
begin
  if not (Prepared) then
  begin
    {DatabaseName := Sessions.CurrentSession.Databases[0].DatabaseName;
    SessionName := Sessions.CurrentSession.SessionName;}
    Connection := FDManager.Connections[0];
    SQL.Clear;
    SQL.Add('insert into asptheade ( ');
    SQL.Add('theade_trans, theade_store,  theade_register, theade_location, ');
    SQL.Add('theade_date, theade_cashier, theade_type, theade_name, ');
    SQL.Add('theade_salesperson, theade_group, theade_group_disc, ');
    SQL.Add('theade_comm_flag, theade_comm_price, theade_cust_code, ');
    SQL.Add('theade_sub_total, ');
    SQL.Add('theade_tax_total, theade_disc_total, theade_grand_total, ');
    SQL.Add('theade_change_amt, theade_drawertime, theade_posted_date, theade_gratuity) ');
    SQL.Add('values ( :d0, :d1, :s2, :s3, ');
    SQL.Add(' current year to second, :s4, :s5, :s6, ');
    SQL.Add(':s7, :s8, :f9, ');
    SQL.Add(':s10, :s11, :s12, :f13, ');
    SQL.Add(':f14, :f15, :f16, :f17, :f18, :f19, :f20 ) ');
    Prepared := True;
  end;
  {SQL.Add( Format( 'values ( %d, %d, "%s", "%s", ',  }
  Params[0].AsInteger := FTrans;
  Params[1].AsInteger := FStore;
  Params[2].AsString := FRegister;
  Params[3].AsString := FLocation;
  {SQL.Add( Format( ' current, "%s", "%s", "%s", ',    }
  Params[4].AsString := FCashier;
  Params[5].AsString := FTransType;
  Params[6].AsString := FStatementText;
  {SQL.Add( Format( '"%s", "%s", %f, ',}
  Params[7].AsString := FSalesPerson;
  Params[8].AsString := FDiscGroup;
  Params[9].AsFloat := FDiscRate * 100;
  {SQL.Add( Format( '"%s", "%s", "%s", %f, ',}
  Params[10].AsString := FCommFlag;
  Params[11].AsString := FCommPrice;
  Params[12].AsString := FCustCode;
  Params[13].AsFloat := FSubTotal;
  {SQL.Add( Format( '%f, %f, %f, %f ) ',}
  Params[14].AsFloat := FTaxTotal;
  Params[15].AsFloat := FDiscTotal;
  Params[16].AsFloat := FGrandTotal;
  Params[17].AsFloat := FChangeAmt;
  Params[18].AsDateTime := FDrawerTime;
  Params[19].AsDateTime := FServiceDate;
  Params[20].AsFloat := FGratuity;

  Execute;
  FValid := True;
end;
FTrans :=   FDManager.Connections[0].GetLastAutoGenValue('asptheade');
QHeaderQuery.Close;
```

I am getting Capability not supported. I even tried empty string instead  of  but again the same error. Can you please guide me with the proper usage of GetLastAutoGenValue? I am using dbExpress bridge driver.

Comment: I think the 'GetLastAutoGenValue' is only supported by the DBMS's that Firedac supports natively, so not by using the DBX bridge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it work out using following query in my stored proc:

```
SELECT DBINFO('sqlca.sqlerrd1') FROM SYSTABLES WHERE tabname = '<tablename>'
```

and return the same value in Stored Proc.

Answer (score 2):

GetLastAutoGenValue supports returning of:

1. the last auto-incremental field value used at Insert / Post for
   all data sources;
2. the last auto-incremental value used at ExecSQL
   / ExecProc for native FireDAC drivers;
3. the last value of sequence / generator for native FireDAC drivers. The GetLastAutoGenValue argument is a generator / sequence name.

FireDAC XE5 does not have native driver for Informix. So, (2) and (3) are not supported for Informix. Your code is INSERT with Execute, so (1) is not supported too. Consequently you are getting "Capability not supported".

Comment: @Copilot provided you a workaround. This is exactly what FireDAC Informix driver is doing in XE6.

Answer (score 2):

You can workaround by executing following query right after the insert query:

```
SELECT DBINFO('sqlca.sqlerrd1') FROM SYSTABLES WHERE tabname = 'systables'
```

Comment: It returns 0 after insert query. Is there any way I can do that using stored proc in informix?

Comment: I believe it returns 0 because the dbinfo-query is not fired right after your insert.  Probably there was some 'hidden' query to the db because of the refreshmode of the FDQuery.  Put the refreshmode to 'rmManual'.  I believe you can do this by a stored proc too, however I've never done it this way before.

Comment: And you're sure your insert has succeeded?  the inserted record is now viewable in the database?  And try using the 'ExecSQL' command instead of Execute.